# How to change my entry point of my angular app to a service?

Tags: angular, build, program-entry-point

My current main.ts is bootstrapping the output-dialog.module, which makes the entry point for the output-dialog.component.ts ... When I build my app, deploy it on Nexus, and I want other apps to use my app/lib, I want them to entry my app via the out-dialog-internal.service.ts with one of its methods. Is there a way to do that?

[image]